# KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' after AKS upgrade

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

Some APIs running on AKS are rasing this error after upgrading AKS from 1.24 to 1.26:

```
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

Does some have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: `Forbidden` would correspond to an HTTP 403 status code, but as to why there's not enough information available. That said, note that Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault is unsupported. Please upgrade to Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys, .Secrets, and/or .Certificates. The authentication model with each of those is different and would also provide more information in an auth failure like this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of RBAC configuration or permissions for accessing the Key Vault were changed due to upgradation of AKS version.

***Need to check below:***

1. Ensure that the user or service principal used to authenticate with the Azure Key Vault has the required permissions.
2. Validate RBAC configuration of AKS cluster has necessary role assignments to provide the required permissions to the user or service principal accessing the Key Vault. Try updating the RBAC configuration to reflect any changes made during the AKS upgrade.
3. Ensure that Key Vault firewall rules or virtual network service endpoints are correctly configured to allow access from your AKS cluster.
4. Enable diagnostic logging for Azure Key Vault and review the logs to get more detailed information about the specific access issue.
5. Review if the settings for the APIs are configured properly and eligible for upgraded version of AKS.
6. Navigate **Diagnose and solve problems** in AKS cluster. Go to **Known Issues, Availability and Performance** section and select **Kubernetes API deprecations**, check if any of the APIs are deprecated.

[image]